# How to check from Linux in Python for administrative access to a Windows machine

Tags: python, windows, remote-access, administrator

I have a network of end-user machines (Windows, Linux, MacOS) and I want to check whether the credential I have allow me to access the machines as administrator (I am checking the "here are the admin credentials to the machines" vs. reality).

I wrote a Python script (it runs on Linux) which

- runs `nmap -O` on the network to gather the hosts
- tries to `ssh` with `paramiko` to check the Linux credentials.

I would like to do a similar check for the Windows machines. What would be a practical way, in Python, to do so?

I have a few sets of credentials (AD or local to a machine) so I would need a somehow universal method. I was thinking about something like a call to `_winreg.ConnectRegistry` but it does not `import` on my Linux (it does on a Windows box).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no sys-admin, but just trying to mount the C-drive ( \hostname\C$ ) via samba/smb should work. This assumes that remote sharing and filesystem access is enabled on that box and the firewall rule setup to allow for remote connections.

Comment: I thought about using `smbclient` (should have noted it in my question) but I was looking for a more portable way (using only Python, without a `subprocess.call`). If there are no such solutions I will do that.